# Left PseudoInverse and Right Pseudoinverse in Linear Algebra

Tags: pseudoinverse

While reading pseudoinverse topic in Linear algebra i got confused in following Statements :

1) Left Pseudoinverse of a matrix is Projection onto Row space of a matrix.
2) Right Pseudoinverse of a matrix is projection onto Column space of a matrix.

Is these statements are true?

Update: Solved

Comment: A pseudoinverse is not (in general) a projection. I suspect your statements are garbled version of some of the claims in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Projectors .

Comment: Thanks i got it